# Допустимы ли неполные ответы на "мульти"-вопрос

Tags: обсуждение

Собственно, есть [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/497759/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-word-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-delphi), вернее даже три, состыкованные в один.
Первый "под-вопрос" достаточно интересен, правда требует (для меня) значительное количество времени, чтобы разобраться, как это сделать (подозреваю, что решение все-таки есть).
На вторую и третью часть, если честно, даже смотреть неохота из-за неполного описания.

1. Корректен ли такой топик, состоящий из нескольких под-вопросов по относительно разным темам?
2. Допустимы ли ответы, содержащие часть решения проблемы (в данном случае - решение одной проблемы из трех)? (да, [справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) допускает подобное, однако соответствует ли это духу сообщества?)

Comment: Закрыл вопрос и оставил автору комментарий с пояснениями.

Comment: UPD: автор отредактировал, я переоткрыл )

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Подобные вопросы, состоящие из нескольких отдельных, очень нежелательны. Они усложняют структурирование информации, выглядят как огромная портянка текста и требуют таких же портянок текста в ответ. С одной стороны, тому, кто найдет это через гугл, будет непросто продираться через весь этот текст, чтобы понять, нужен ли он ему. С другой - отвечающих подобные вопросы тоже только демотивируют.
2. Конечно, отвечать на такие вопросы можно. Даже будучи неполными, ответы будут оценены автором вопроса и сообществом. Однако, сначала стоит попробовать убедить автора разбить вопрос на несколько.